# Does a USB-C (female) to HDMI (male) adapter exist

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, usb-c, display-adapter

I have 2 computers, and one iPad.

- My desktop computer runs Windows 10, and has an open HDMI.
- My laptop is a MacBook Pro, and has HDMI and Micro DisplayPort.

I am looking at the feasibility of getting a [Luna Display](https://shop.astropad.com/collections/luna-display-mac-and-pc/products/preorder-luna-display-for-windows?variant=34351865528452) of the USB-C variety (As that's the only one that works on Windows and macOS interchangeably)

Luna display says that it doesn't work with adapters. (I've emailed them a few times, and that's not actually the case. It only "usually" doesn't work with adapters) But, since I'm a bit crazy, I figured I'd at least look into this:

Is it possible to make a cable or adapter that has USB-C female, with the DisplayPort over USB-C specification on one end, and a male HDMI on the other?

I've searched far and wide on the internet for one, to no avail, and I am not an technician by any stretch of the imagination. I took a glance at the pinouts, and couldn't make heads or tails of them.

Comment: I know for a fact that full sized displayport at the PC will output HDMI happily. <video> over USB C is unfortunately a bit of a mess.

Comment: “I took a glance at the pinouts, and couldn't make heads or tails of them.” FWIW, none of what you are attempting to do has anything to do with pinouts. USB C pinouts and HDMI pinouts are all data/digital. Meaning it’s not like you could simply count pinouts and if they match in some way, that would mean something.

Comment: I doubt that you can even find an adapter to get it connected to the (I think it's mini instead of micro) DP on your MBP. It seems to be a silly choise that they chose to produce a USB-C variant instead of a full size DP variant. Perhaps it has certain power requirement? (But then I wonder why there's the HDMI variant; don't know it provides more power though). Even active converter that converts TMDS signal to DP signal seems to be scarce

Comment: Besides, where do you get `(As that's the only one that works on Windows and macOS interchangeably)` from?

Comment: I've emailed them a couple times, and they mentioned that the mdp version is Mac specific, the hdmi is windows specific, and the usb-c is interchangeable.

Comment: The reason I was looking at pinouts was because I was interested in how adapters work... I'm not sure how that had nothing to do with what I'm attempting... As I'd even be so inclined as to try to build my own adapter if need be